# What is the main issue existing with local system account?

Tags: windows

In our product documentation it is written that

> If your local security  measures require, you can change the user account and password under which the main Server services run.
>
> You must have Administrator privileges to change the service account.
>
> Note that the main Server services cannot run using the local system account.

Here then what is the problems with that account, when i did a search i came to know that `LocalSystem` service can do things that would bring down the entire system or damage the entire system.

Does that the real problem?

Where do we can see that account.

I think the actual name of the account is NT AUTHORITY\System.

Comment: the system account is the utter core of Windows. it exists at a level above "administrator" and should never be used by anything/anyone other than actual system services. If 'administrator' is the equivalent of 'root', then 'system' is the HR officer who hired 'administrator'.

Comment: what you mean by actual system services?

Comment: pop up task manager, "display processes from all users". You'll see what's running under system. Things like 'lsass', 'wininit', 'winlogon', etc.. All processes that, if killed, will immediately crash your system.

Comment: thanks,but then whats the problem if i use that in to my services, will it be the issue which i pointed in my question

Comment: If you're running your own code under the 'system' account, you'd better be VERY sure it's bulletproof code. System has COMPLETELY access to EVERYTHING in windows, and you can trivially kill the box with a simple bad memory address. There are no safeguards when running under SYSTEM.

Comment: @Marc B - no more so than other applications (AFAIK) ... it is more about default permissions than anything else.

Comment: [Related topic for Linux/Unix](http://superuser.com/questions/218379/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root/)

Comment: It's incorrect that bad memory accesses can kill the box when running under the SYSTEM account. That can only happen in kernel mode (such as with a buggy driver), while *lsass*, *winlogon* and such are still user-mode processes. *However,* the SYSTEM account has privileges to use various API functions for accessing memory or executing code in other processes (including the security subsystem) or even loading custom drivers. If the program is buggy, a well-aimed exploit can do Bad Things to the system.

Answer (score 4):

Local system is one of the few built in groups.

Anything that runs as system has **full** local control over your computer and can do anything/everything they want to.

So as for your questions (I think).

`Q:` When i did a search i came to know that LocalSystem service can do things that would bring down the entire system or damage the entire system.Does that the real problem?

`A:` As I said, Processes under system can do pretty much anything they want. The usual processes that run under this account include AV, Firewall and other similar programs. It has a lot of power and should only be used when required.

`Q:`Where do we can see that account .I think the actual name of the account is NT AUTHORITY\System.

`A:` It is a system managed account, you cannot see it as such and it would be a bad idea if you could.... If you really want to do it, take a copy of `c:\windows\system32\osk.exe` and then copy `c:\windows\explorer.exe` to `c:\windows\system32\osk.exe`.

Go to the login screen (which runs as system, so you should understand the power of this account!), then click on accessibilities control (the circle-ish icon in the bottom left hand corner) and launch the on screen keyboard.

You will now have an instance of explorer running as system that has full control over everything!

Comment: Interesting trick with `osk.exe`.

Comment: [`psexec -desi cmd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) is easier

Comment: It's simple to say, but it's not actually true.  `Local System` does _not_ have "full control over everything".  It has no network credentials (beyond the machine account), for example.  And ACLs that deny it access will work just as they do for other accounts.  Windows NT is not Unix.  It doesn't have special accounts that it stops making all security checks for, and that can "do everything" therefore.  The dangers of `Local System` are that it has access to system processes that run under that account, access to the SAM, and the TCB privilege.  Let's not confuse people with hyperbole.

Comment: @jdeBP Well, full control over everything "local by default"... 3 additional words, but, in the context of the question, I was trying to keep it simple!

Comment: Simplifying to the point of incorrectness will only cause confusion.  Your saying "full control" is a case in point.  That has a specific meaning on Windows NT, and it is _not_ the case that `Local System` has full control even if one is only considering local resources.  [Since Windows NT 6.0, `Local System` has not had full control access to operating system executable files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2007.06.acl.aspx), for example.  There is **no** account in Windows NT that bypasses security controls and has full access to everything.  It's not Unix.

Comment: @HdeBP - By default, Local System does have access to everything **and** it is pretty silly to think that just because you have full access, you can do anything on a remote system...