# I created an Ubuntu server. Do I have a "root" user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

I always thought "root" was a default user created when you install basically any Linux. During installation, it asked me to choose a username, so I picked "devadmin". Is that my "root" user now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a single user, who can use `sudo`.

To become actually root:

```
sudo su
```

To HAVE a root account:

```
sudo passwd root
```

(then type a new password, and that will be your new root account's password.)

Comment: Is there any reason to make a root account? Also, with a root account do you still have to type sudo, or does root have all permissions without sudo-ing?

Comment: @orokusaki [It's bad to run everything as root](http://superuser.com/questions/218379/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root/218387#218387). You don't work as `SYSTEM` on Windows either. Your regular user is probably a `sudoer` (`man sudo`/`man sudoers`) though, so you can "become root" for specific administrative tasks limited in scope.

Comment: @DanielBeck: There is nothing wrong with having a root user on your computer. Sure, great power, comes with great responsibility. But you can do stupid things even with sudo. Or even as a single user. So it's not like you break anything. (And root is been around for ever. Only Ubuntu started this trend, to disable it and have a sudo instead.)

Comment: @orokusaki  The `root` account always exists, but by default does not have a password (so you cannot actually log in to the system as `root`). The second command shown here first makes you impersonate `root`, and then sets a password. This'll allow you to log in as `root`, if you really want to (unless you have a very good reason, you probably don't).

Comment: Note that `sudo su` can be replaced by `sudo -s`. Both open a root shell for the current user who must be a sudoer.

Comment: @Shiki It might be true that only Ubuntu started it rather recently (and I seriously doubt it), but that doesn't mean using the root account like a regular user account isn't a bad idea. `--no-preserve-root` is also a pretty recent addition to `rm`. Chances are, given the question, orokusaki is not experienced enough to be aware of all the implications. It's only safe advice to say: Unless there's a very good reason, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the comments. I've actually learned a lot from the answer and the comments here.

Comment: If I accidentally misnamed my user account during the initial installation, for example if I type "devdmin" instead of "devadmin", is there a way to change that account username?

The reason I ask is because I created an ubuntu server VM on VirtualBox, and when I mount a shared folder, it says it belongs to my misnamed initial user account, e.g. "devdmin". Now I have to use sudo to edit any of the files within the shared folder.

Answer (score 4):

On every Linux system, there is a `root` account. It's safer to not use it for everyday tasks though, because [careless typos on the command shell or bugs in software could otherwise seriously mess up your system](https://superuser.com/questions/218379/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root).

The `root` account might not have a password, so you're not able to directly log in as `root`. But your primary user account is probably one of the `sudoers`, users able to use the `sudo` program to execute specific programs as root (`sudo whoami`) or, for longer administrative tasks requiring multiple steps, open a shell as root (`sudo -s`).

By running `sudo passwd`, you can set a password for `root` if you really need it, but it's likely that you don't and will just invite accidents like accidental file deletions.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a root shell for a longer time you could use the -s option with the **sudo** command:

Just type

```
sudo -s
```

to create a permanent root shell. And type

```
exit
```

to leave the root shell when you're done with your work.